# Large cURL request's JSON response is truncated in PHP, but not when using my browser

Tags: php, json, curl

I am making a cURL request to https://example.com?params=xyz, which returns a relatively large JSON response of 600kb~.

When I echo the output in PHP, I can see that the JSON response is truncated abruptly midway.

But if I paste the url for the cURL request into my browser, the response shows up in its full form, which leads me to believe it must be an issue on my end, but I checked my php.ini and the max cache size was like 65M or something very large, so I'm not sure what could be causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: The cURL request was taking 4.5~ seconds.

Changing `curl_setopt($curl_array[$request_label], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);` to `curl_setopt($curl_array[$request_label], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 7);` fixed the incomplete JSON response.